# render plot before completing interactive selections with selectizeInput in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I would like r shiny to generate graphics without requiring all selectizeInput fields. In this way I'd like the first plot to be general (a plot of vehicles of all cyl values within a class), and then tailor the plot to be more specific with the ability to view only cyl values of interest. My code does not currently generate a plot until the second (cyl) selection is made.

To be as specific as possible here is what I'm hoping to produce:

1. An app that initiates with class 'compact' and a plot of 'year' vs. 'hwy' for ALL values of 'cyl'
2. The ability to select a subset of 'cyl' values using the second dropdown box

Reproducible code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


data("mpg")
mpg


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("loc_lev_1", label = "Vehicle Type", choices = unique(mpg$class)),
      
      selectizeInput("loc_lev_2", label = "cyl", choices = unique(mpg$cyl),
                     multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL),
      
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  loc_lev_1 <- reactive({
    filter(mpg, class == input$loc_lev_1)
  })
  
  observeEvent(loc_lev_1(), {
    choices <- unique(loc_lev_1()$cyl)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "loc_lev_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    mpg %>%
      filter(class == input$loc_lev_1) %>%
      filter(cyl %in% input$loc_lev_2) %>%
      
      ggplot(aes(x = year, y = hwy)) +  
      geom_point() +
      geom_smooth() +
      
      labs(title = paste(input$loc_lev_1)) +
      theme_minimal() +
      theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just check if `input$loc_lev_2` is not null; in that case add the filter on cylinder, otherwise dont.  Here is an example:

```
get_plot <- function(car_class, cylinder) {

  gginput <- filter(mpg, class==car_class)
  if(!is.null(cylinder)) {
    gginput <- filter(gginput, cyl %in% cylinder)
  }

  p <- ggplot(data = gginput, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +

    labs(title = paste(car_class)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())

  return(p)
}
```

Then render like this:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot(get_plot(input$loc_lev_1, input$loc_lev_2))
```

You can see split the logic out into a function, but it is not necessary; you can keep it all in the `renderPlot()` call if you like.

#### Full Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)


data("mpg")

get_plot <- function(car_class, cylinder) {

  gginput <- filter(mpg, class==car_class)
  if(!is.null(cylinder)) {
    gginput <- filter(gginput, cyl %in% cylinder)
  }

  p <- ggplot(data = gginput, aes(x = year, y = hwy)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() +

    labs(title = paste(car_class)) +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.position = "bottom", plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), panel.grid.minor=element_blank())

  return(p)
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectizeInput("loc_lev_1", label = "Vehicle Type", choices = unique(mpg$class)),

      selectizeInput("loc_lev_2", label = "cyl", choices = unique(mpg$cyl),
                     multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL),


    ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  loc_lev_1 <- reactive({
    filter(mpg, class == input$loc_lev_1)
  })

  observeEvent(loc_lev_1(), {
    choices <- unique(loc_lev_1()$cyl)
    updateSelectizeInput(session, "loc_lev_2", choices = choices)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot(get_plot(input$loc_lev_1, input$loc_lev_2))

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you langtang. This gets me very close. However, there are only 3 levels of cyl for class compact (4,5,6). The app allows me to choose all levels of cyl for the global dataset (4,5,6,8). I'd like the second selectizeInput to only display the available levels of cyl for the chosen class.

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean. When I run this app, only 4,5,6 are shown as choices for "compact"

Comment: langtang, try as I may I cannot reproduce this. I am seeing (4,5,6,8) as choices for compact. Could you please share your code so that I can see what I am missing?

Comment: hi there! - I have added my full code, which does not change your observe event call, which should filter the availble choices for cylinder (and when i launch this app, compact is the first choice, and only 4,5,6 are available.  However, I would add that gnerating the `loc_level_1` reactive the way you do is bit redundant..

Comment: Thank you langtang. This solution worked. I will ponder how to reduce redundancy.